# C# compare window title

Tags: c#, winforms, window

How can I compare if my active application/window title is equal to something? For example, I want my WinForms application to only execute its functions when a certain application is in focus.

I tried using `GetForegroundWindow()` but it's not working.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetForegroundWindow().ToString() == "Test123")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("right");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("wrong");
    }
```

So my timer was going to check if the current window title is called "Test123" (note: not the process name, just the window title text), and tell me if it's right or wrong.

Comment: I can't seem to get the window title. I don't know what it's trying to return to me.

Comment: It's just returning you an `IntPtr` of the window. You need to take that pass it to another Win32 API call to give you the actual title.

Comment: Where do you wire up the timer1_Tick event handler to timer1?

Answer (score 2):

`GetForegroundWindow()` just returns you an `IntPtr`. This is your window handle (`hWnd`) for other calls to get information.

In this case, to get the window text you need to use [`GetWindowText`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext). Implement that and pass in your newly acquired `IntPtr` (hWnd).